# How do I invoke the IE 'onblur' event from VBA code in Excel?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, onblur

Situation:  I am working to populate text entry boxes in a webpage with data from Excel.  When the data is entered manually and the focus is moved to another text box, the 'onblur' event is fired to do input validation.

Desire:  I want to be able to cause the 'onblur' event to be fired when I populate the same text boxes from VBA code in Excel.

Question:  How do I cause the 'onblur' event to be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have access to the DOM, in which case you should be able to use

```
document.getElementById(*element*).fireEvent("onblur");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, you want to know the VBA equivlant of OnBlur. That event is MyTextBox_Exit in VBA.