# How do I submit data after entering text to a web form

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have put some code together that will open a web page and enter values from my excel sheet to the web form. What i would like to do next is "submit" the values so the web page can do the calcs, then i can read the values back to my excel sheet.

My problem is when entering the values manually pressing "tab" submits the data and the webpage does the calc. I cant replicate this Tab press in vba?

code as it stands:

```
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Maj As Variant 'varient handles decimal places. Maj= major Ø
    Dim TPI As Variant
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://eicac.co.uk/Acme-Stub-Thread-Calculator"
    
    Do While IE.busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Maj = Range("a1").Value 'Store A1 as Maj
    TPI = Range("a2").Value
    
    'MsgBox (maj) 'test
    
    
    IE.document.getelementbyid("p1C3").Value = Maj
    IE.document.getelementbyid("p1C4").Value = TPI
    IE.document.getelementbyid("p1C4").Focus
    With Application
      .SendKeys "{TAB}"
    
        End With
    
    
    


    

          
    
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I think I'm sending the "tab" command to vba instead of IE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need to trigger the input's `onblur` event after setting the value.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059069/how-do-i-invoke-the-ie-onblur-event-from-vba-code-in-excel

Comment: Perfect @Tim Williams, worked like a dream!